# Package Inputenc Error with morefloats package

Tags: packages, unicode, input-encodings

Herewith package morefloats, I got the error message saying
Package inputenc Error: Unicode character (inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX. \usepackage{morefloats}

I'm wondering if anyone can help me out with this error?

Comment: I don't know, but anyway, if you have a comparatively recent vversion of latex, you don't have to load inputenc: utf8  is now the default.

Comment: Show a small but *complete* example that triggers the error. Then we can test if we can reproduce it.